# PHP < 5.3 Difference between two times hours::min

Tags: php, datetime, date, datediff

Unfortunately I cannot use `DateTime::Diff` and am looking for a way to convert my current format of datetime so I may subtract and find the difference in hours and minutes, something like this:

```
// 2:11pm 2-20-2012
$opendate = '2012-02-20T14:11:03-05:00';

// 6:22pm 2-20-2012
$closedate = '2012-02-20T18:22:50-05:00';

$diff_date = $closedate - $opendate
```

I would like `$diff_date` to return in hours::minutes format, such as '4 hrs 11 min'.

If it would be beneficial for this, another alternative to the times formatted above is:

```
        $removeT = "T";
        $replaceSPACE = " ";
//returns datetime like '2012-02-20 14:11:03'
        $r = str_replace($removeT, $replaceSPACE, $opendate[$i]);
        $r = substr($r, 0, 19);
//returns datetime like '2012-02-20 18:22:50'
        $s = str_replace($removeT, $replaceSPACE, $closedate[$i]);
        $s = substr($s, 0, 19);
```

Comment: Check this out, this should give you what you need:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert both to UNIX-timestamp, then subtract one from the other. You can convert to result to hours and minutes very easy.

```
$secondsDiff = strtotime($closedate) - strtotime($opendate);
```

Comment: Ok im very new to php, but from my understanding I would convert those time "values" to UNIX using `mktime()`?

Comment: This worked beautifully, this converts it into seconds. I'll do math to figure out hours and minutes thank you.

Comment: You use `mktime()`, when you have every time component (hour, minute, ...) on its own. `strtotime()` tries to parse a formatted time-string into a timestamp (quite useful in conjunction with `date()`).